# Ruby on Rails, transfer submit_tag to a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, submit

I have a following structure:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#check_all').on("click", function(){ $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(); });
</script> 
   <%= form_tag what_to_do_files_path, method: :get do %>
   <%= submit_tag "Delete selected", :commit =>"delete" %>
   <%= submit_tag "Pictures/Info/Raw Int", :commit =>"pictures" %>
   <button type="button" id="check_all">Check / Uncheck All </button>

   lalala
   <%end%>
```

As you may have noticed the buttons "Delete" and "Pictures/.." differe from "Ceck /Un..". I need then to look like a "Ceck / Uncheck buttom"
I have tried to use

```
<%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn btn-default", value:"my_button") do %>
    Update list <i class="icon-repeat"></i>
<% end %>
```

But params[:commit] does not catch it. 

What is the problem and how can I transfer a submit_tag into a button?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Also, see [Railscasts Episode 38 Multibutton forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form).

Try this

```
# form

<%= form_tag what_to_do_files_path do %>
 ...
 ...
 ...
  <%= button_tag :class => "btn btn-warning", :name => 'delete' do %> Delete selected <% end %>
  <%= button_tag :class => "btn btn-primary", :name => 'pictures' do %> Pictures/Info/Raw Int <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Your action would look something like this:

```
# controller

def what_to_do_files
  if params[:delete]
    # Do stuff for delete
  elsif params[:pictures]
    # Do stuff for pictures
  else
    # other commit
  end
end
```

Comment: It is possible somehow to use just params[:commit] in order to catch what button was pressed? I used method=params[:commit], so that I store what was cliked and I would like not to change it

Comment: and the buttons "Delete..." and "Pictures.." still differ from "Check /Uncheck.."